# How upload file with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I trying to upload video file with selenium, it doesn't work

my code:

`a = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, 'input'))) browser.execute_script("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible'", a) a.send_keys("C:/Users/NIKITA/Desktop/vk_clips/testvid.mp4")`

[image]

This script works but doesn't load the file and doesn't throw an error. I tried searching for the element using XPath, it causes a timeout exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web element actually accepting the uploaded file is matching this XPath: `"//input[@type='file']"`. This element is not visible. You can see yourself on picture you shared `visibility: hidden`.
Again, this is not an element you clicking when uploading file manually as a user via the GUI.
So, to upload file to it you can not wait for it to become visible or clickable.
Just wait for this element presence.
Your code can be something like the following:

```py
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']"))).send_keys("C:/Users/NIKITA/Desktop/vk_clips/testvid.mp4")
```

Comment: Is there any way I can make the element visible?

Comment: No. And you should not. Selenium imitates human actions on the web page. This element is not visible by human user. It receives the uploaded file internally when you clicking the `upload` button on the presented menu. But with Selenium we can do this action directly. Not good enough?